# Simple Algebra manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra

I was struggling to see the steps for this. I tried adding +b-b to the numerator:

$$\frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{a}}$$

Comment: Just divide numerator and denominator by $a$.

Comment: Hint: $1+\frac{b}{a} = \frac{a}{a}+ \frac{b}{a}$ (when $a\neq 0$).

Comment: Factor out $a$ in the denominator and simplify with the numerator.

Comment: a should be nonzero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{b}{a}} = \frac{a}{a + \frac{b}{a}*a}$ we multiply by $a$ in the numerator and denominator and simplify to get

$=\frac{a}{a + b}$